# How to set up a custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I wish I could design a keyboard layout of my own (specifying symbols for each the key to be entered in case it is pressed alone, with <kbd>Shift</kbd> or with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) and set it up among all the other layouts in my XUbuntu 11.04 system. How to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 10.10

I use a local keyboard with US and Thai layout.
The `us` layout is ok for me, but I like to have some
additional german characters like `äöü ÄÖÜ`
This can easy be implemented with `xmodmap`, but if 
you switch to the second layout, you will observe 
some strange results.

I found a good solution: create and use your custom keyboard!

1. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`
   choose your nearest preference, in my case `us`
   and save it with a new name: `us-de`
2. delete anything, which you don't need, and change, 
   what ever you like. My file for `us-de`:

   ```
   default
   xkb_symbols "basic" {

   name[Group1]= "ASCII with german";

   // Alphanumeric section
   key <TLDE> { [ grave, asciitilde ] };
   key <AE01> { [ 1, exclam ] };
   key <AE02> { [ 2, at, twosuperior ] };
   key <AE03> { [ 3, numbersign, threesuperior ] };
   key <AE04> { [ 4, dollar, onequarter ] };
   key <AE05> { [ 5, percent, onehalf ] };
   key <AE06> { [ 6, asciicircum, threequarters ] };
   key <AE07> { [ 7, ampersand ] };
   key <AE08> { [ 8, asterisk, oneeighth ] };
   key <AE09> { [ 9, parenleft ] };
   key <AE10> { [ 0, parenright, degree ] };
   key <AE11> { [ minus, underscore ] };
   key <AE12> { [ equal, plus ] };

   key <AD01> { [ q, Q ] };
   key <AD02> { [ w, W ] };
   key <AD03> { [ e, E, EuroSign, cent ] };
   key <AD04> { [ r, R ] };
   key <AD05> { [ t, T ] };
   key <AD06> { [ y, Y ] };
   key <AD07> { [ u, U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
   key <AD08> { [ i, I ] };
   key <AD09> { [ o, O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
   key <AD10> { [ p, P ] };
   key <AD11> { [ bracketleft, braceleft ] };
   key <AD12> { [ bracketright, braceright ] };

   key <AC01> { [ a, A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
   key <AC02> { [ s, S ] };
   key <AC03> { [ d, D ] };
   key <AC04> { [ f, F ] };
   key <AC05> { [ g, G ] };
   key <AC06> { [ h, H ] };
   key <AC07> { [ j, J ] };
   key <AC08> { [ k, K ] };
   key <AC09> { [ l, L ] };
   key <AC10> { [ semicolon, colon ] };
   key <AC11> { [ apostrophe, quotedbl ] };

   key <AB01> { [ z, Z ] };
   key <AB02> { [ x, X ] };
   key <AB03> { [ c, C ] };
   key <AB04> { [ v, V ] };
   key <AB05> { [ b, B ] };
   key <AB06> { [ n, N ] };
   key <AB07> { [ m, M, mu ] };
   key <AB08> { [ comma, less ] };
   key <AB09> { [ period, greater ] };
   key <AB10> { [ slash, question ] };

   key <BKSL> { [ backslash, bar ] };
   key <CAPS> { [ VoidSymbol ] };

   // End alphanumeric section
   include "level3(ralt_switch)"
   };
   ```
3. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`
   Modify `evdev.xml` so your custom keyboard will be recognised:
   search for `</layoutList>` and 
   add the following just before `</layoutList>`:

   ```
   <layout>
   <configItem>
   <name>us-de</name> <!-- a) -->
   <shortDescription>US-DE</shortDescription> <!-- b) -->
   <description>ASCII with german</description> <!-- c) -->
   <languageList><iso639Id>eng</iso639Id></languageList> <!-- d) -->
   </configItem>
   </layout>
   ```

   - a) `us-de` is the filename of the new keyboard layout in `X11/xkb/symbols`
   - b) `US-DE` this will appear eg. in the indicator applet
   - c) `ASCII with german` must coincide with the text at the begin of your file:
     `name[Group1]= "ASCII with german"`;
     This text will also appear as comment under "Layouts"
   - d) if you choose "eng" your layout will be shown in 
     System->Preferences->Keyboard->tab Layouts->Add->By Language->English
     under "Variants"
4. log out and log in again, and check 
   System->Preferences->Keyboard->tab Layouts->Add->By Language->English
   if you can find your custom layout, happy! You are ready to go!
   Select your first and second layou here. Add a keyboard switcher applet
   here under "options" you can also disable the CapsLock key.
5. the default keyboard will annoy you and sometime reappear... 
   If you like to get rid of this, edit `/var/cache/gdm/$USER/dmrc`
   and place anything existing as your new default: `Layout=us-de`
   then reboot.

Based on [a post on UbuntuForums.com by Andy Meier at December 28th, 2010](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1654199&highlight=.Xmodmap).

Comment: thank you so much for this post... i have been searching for so long!

Comment: Instead of provide only a link, you should write the useful parts *here*.

Comment: Just a little update on this. I was changing my italian keyboard to add `ə` and I have had some troubles. This was because if you want to change for instance
`key <AE03> { [ 3, numbersign, threesuperior ] };`, you should replace the character - for instance `numbersign` - with the proper code point, that in my case is `U0269`. So the final entry will be: `key <AE03> { [ 3, U0269, threesuperior ] };`
Now I can type `ə` just clicking `Shift+3`