# Where can I find the layout maps for the variety of options when working with "Layout of numeric keypad?"

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode, compose-key, numpad

I set up my keyboard to have a "**compose**" key on my Ubuntu 21.04 system.  I love the flexibility!  When exploring (`System Settings`-`Hardware`-`Input Devices`-`Keyboard`-`Advanced`), I discovered the `Layout of numeric keypad` selection.  There are options there like `ATM/phone-style`, `Hexadecimal`, `Unicode additions`, etc.

I am very interested in both the `Hexadecimal` and the `Unicode additions...` However, I have not been able to find the layout mapping in order to choose whether to have a new **keypad layout** or leave it alone.

Where does one find the reference material for this feature?

***UPDATE***
I am reviewing this questin ([How to set up a custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72177/how-to-set-up-a-custom-keyboard-layout)) and its answer.  While not
exactly the same question, they are related.  If I glean a solution
while perusing that question, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Those are XKB options. I'm not aware of any related documentation, but you can always explore the files under the `/usr/share/X11/xkb` directory.

Comment: I'll try that out... So, there is no official documentation about keyboard management?

Comment: It is like reading a Martian document... I see no explanation for why things are the way they are and, thus, without specialized knowledge unavailable to me.

Comment: @TheGeeko61: I can't tell for sure that there is no relevant documentation; just saying that I'm not aware of any. If I was you I would simply try those options out and see what happens.

Comment: @Ginnar:  that's exactly what I did which is why I said it was like reading Martian documents. :)  Sure, one could spend weeks tearing those documents apart in order to see what patterns might emerge and be useful.

Comment: @TheGeeko61: I think you misunderstood my last sentence. What I meant was trying the options out from the KDE gui (you are on Kubuntu, right?) and study the effects.